# All mailers seemingly being ignored (mail not being generated in development or staging)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have been working on upgrading our app from Rails 3.2 to 4.2. As I've done some testing in the browser I noticed that no email was being generated through the `letter_opener` gem in my browser in development, and no email was being sent out in staging. I started watching the console logs as I did the testing and saw that the mail templates weren't even being generated. There are no errors. When I switch back to my master branch (with Rails 3), everything works fine. It's like my mailers are just being ignored.

For example, the User model has a `send_welcome_email` callback that looks like this:

```
# user.rb

after_create :send_welcome_email

def send_welcome_email
  if self.email
    CustomerMailer.welcome(self.id)
  end
end
```

The `welcome` method looks like this:

```
# customer_mailer.rb

  def welcome(user_id)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    msg = mail(subject: "Welcome to Sweeps!",
              to: @user.email,
              tag: 'customer welcome')
    msg.deliver  # also tried .deliver_now
  end
```

If I place `binding.pry` inside the `CustomerMailer.welcome` method, I never get a console prompt in my logs like I would expect, which is why I think the mailer is just being ignored altogether.

Here are my environments' mail settings:

```
# development.rb

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener

# staging.rb

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mandrill
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'staging.myapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://staging.myapp.com"
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#calling-the-mailer), you might just be missing asking the mailer to actually deliver the mail with `deliver_now` or `deliver_later`. This should be called *outside* of the mailer class for the mailer method to be called.

```
# user.rb

after_create :send_welcome_email

def send_welcome_email
  if self.email
    CustomerMailer.welcome(self.id).deliver_now
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep, it looks like `deliver_now` has to be called that way now. If you look at my original post, I was creating a `msg` in the mailer method and then calling `.deliver` on that and it worked in Rails 3. Looks like I need to change all those!

Comment: Oh yes you're right, I was too accustomed to calling `deliver` outside of mailer class :) I'll edit it.